# Capturing output of 'at'

Tags: ubuntu, cron, curl, at

How can I log the output of a command executed by [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/at.1.html)?

This command is actually being `exec()`'d by PHP as in:

```
<?php
exec('echo "curl -k https://localhost/projekt/crons/purge/5" | at now + 5 minutes');
```

I need to capture the response from the curl request and log it to a file. The man pages state:

> The user  will  be  mailed  standard  error  and  standard  output
>   from his commands,  if   any.    Mail   will   be   sent   using   the
>   command `/usr/lib/sendmail`.   If **at** is executed from a
>   [su](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/su.1.html)**(1)** shell, the owner of the login shell will receive the
>   mail.

Who owns the mail (www-data?), and how can I access it? Are the docs referring to OS mail belonging to a user, or, actual email? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`$ echo "curl -k https://localhost/projekt/crons/purge/5 > projekt.log 2>&1" | at now + 5 minutes`

Comment: Works great, thanks for putting me on the right path. I found `>>`is append whereas `>` is (over)write. Thanks. The other option, I suppose, would be to just write the log file using PHP inside the call to `https://localhost/projekt/crons/purge/5`. Cheers.